# weird characters instead of yellow page error in asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, iis

I need to fix problem in asp.net website, but instead of yellow page error I get a white page with weird characters.

I know that the problem happens in connection between SQL server and the application.

- I don't have the source code of the application because more than one year it works fine.

[image: weird characters instead of yellow page error]

Can anyone help how to get the yellow page error instead of this.

And I'm sorry about my bad language.

Comment: Do other users have the same problem? If they don't: what changed on your local system? If they do: did something change on the server?

Comment: yes the same problem in all machines ,, my admin of my local system i think is change something in SQL server but he don't remember

Comment: i need to see yellow page error to see the problem and fix it

Answer (score 2):

Please check if the ASP.NET application on which you are working utilizes some form of automatic GZip compression. Your error page is very reminiscent of what Rick Strahl has described at below link.

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/02/ASPNET-GZip-Encoding-Caveats

You can find solution for the problem in same blog spot.

Comment: Additionally you can try below workaround.

Go to your Global.asax.cs file and add this code in the Application_Error event:

 HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;

 app.Response.Filter = null;

Comment: but i don't have the source code of this application for edit global file